# Which of these two sentences are correct, or are they both wrong?

Tags: grammaticality, copular-verbs

1. ...so that they all turn into failures, not that they don't already are.
2. ...so that they all turn into failures, not that they aren't already.

Comment: They can't both _be_ failures and at the same time turn into them, whatever the grammar.

Comment: Neither one is a sentence.  We need to see the rest.

Comment: (But the first is incorrecter than the second.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence translates to

> So that they all turn into failures, not that they do not already are

This does not make sense at all and is wrong.

The second sentence translates to

> So that they all turn into failures, not that they are not (failures)
>   already

This is correct.

Note that with slight modification, the first sentence can be made correct. Consider

> So that they all turn into failures, not that they not already are
>   (failures)

This is also correct.

Comment: Thank you for your response; however, though I know that "do" does not usually couple up with "be", I was thinking of the use in imperative sayings such as "do be quiet pls" or "don't be shy, just try it for once".

Comment: Maybe the above usage is strictly only allowed in imperative structure?

Comment: Thank you so much! I've always wondered if "do" can be used along with "be" outside of imperative sentences.